# jQuery this inside this

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery which isnt working, and I think the answer may because I am using "this" inside "this".

```
  $('.field-name-field-choose-a-service input:checked').each(function() {
    var unitname = $(this).closest('.form-item').text();
    $('.field-name-field-choose-a-package .form-type-checkbox').each(function() {

      if($(this).children('.views-field-field-bookable-unit-type span').text() == unitname) {
        $(this).show();

      } 
    });

  });
```

How do I get "this" to only apply to whats happening in the current function?

Sorry if this isnt detailed enough, im a bit of a newbie to jQuery!

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: You can cache `this` outside of inner `each`. Add `var $checkedService = $(this);` at the beginning of outer `each` and use this inside inner `each`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're inside the context of another `.each()`, the meaning of "this" changes therein.  If you need a reference to the "outer this", capture it in a variable:

```
$('.field-name-field-choose-a-service input:checked').each(function() {
    var outerThis = this;
    var unitname = $(this).closest('.form-item').text();
    $('.field-name-field-choose-a-package .form-type-checkbox').each(function() {
        // "this" refers to the "inner this"
        // "outerThis" refers to the "outer this"
    });
});
```

});

Comment: I think OP want to cache `$(this)` so that jQuery methods can be called on it directly.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I will accept this when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing `$(this)` element in a variable and then using variable instead of using `$(this)`

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361). For now, I've edited the answer.